# Could anyone help me with the make and model of my bmx please

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I got this bmx from a house clearance couple years ago. It never came with any brakes and now I'm trying to source a brake kit for it so I can restore it for my son. It has codes on the bottom but Google comes up with nothing. If anyone could tell me make please so I can order a brake kit for it.

Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated Observation - the front fork is on backward - the dropouts should be in front not behind as pictured.  I bet its twitchy to ride straight and very hard to ride no-handed.

Comment: Yea i thought as much. Poor thing just been sitting in the garden for couple years. Haven't rode it myself. Maybe up and down the road but gonna restore it for my son. Fresh paint, stickers and brakes if I can find any. All fails I'll just take it to a bike shop.

Answer (score 1):

There are clearly visible pegs for U brakes in the frame.  At some point in the past, someone has removed those parts.

Any BMX **U brake** should fit, but you'll need inner/outer wires as well as two brake levers.

You cannot use a V brake, or disk brakes on this frame because the mounts are not there.

There's a chance the grips will not come off cleanly, you might need to replace the rubber grips as well.  Sometimes they just slide off, can't tell till you try.

---

Clarification: this frame uses **U Brakes** whereas V brakes are more from mountain bikes and will NOT be suitable for this frame.

[image]

Notice how the pivot bolts are above the pads in the U brake (left) and below the brake pads in the V brake (right)  This is why the two systems are not interchangeable.

You will need to buy:

- two U brake sets, which will come with brake pads
- two brake levers, a left and a right, with clamps sized to fit the handle bars, probably 22.2mm
- possibly 4x bolts to secure the brakes to the frame - can't tell if they're still in the bike, or they might come with the U brakes.
- two inner brake cables with ends to fit those brake levers.
- some outer brake cable and ferrules.

It is possible to buy "brake refurb kits" that will have one brake's worth of outer and an inner, along with the ferrules and crimps.  You can also get the outer in black or white or sometimes funky colours.

If this all feels like a bit much, look around your area for a Bike Cooperative who can help you learn, and provides access to their tools.  This task can be done with normal garage tools, but a brake wire cutter+crimp can make it a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you for the info mate. I'll have a look at v brakes thanks.

Comment: @Chris your comment says _I'll have a look at v brakes_. Did you mean to say v brakes or u brakes? As Criggie says, they are not interchangeable, there is plenty of information about this on the web.

Comment: @pateksan thank you - I've expanded on the difference.   Some languages don't have a difference between V and U which can be messy, and visually they're similar.  Also, U brakes are only ever used on BMX where V brakes are a lot more common.